# how do I filter an array in coffeescript

Tags: jquery, arrays, filter, coffeescript, addclass

I have a bunch of li elements and I'd like to find the one with a specific value. e.g.

```
<li class="nav"><span>One</span><li>
<li class="nav"><span>Two</span><li>
<li class="nav"><span>Three</span><li>
```

how do I find the the one where the span text is Two and then add a class to its parent li element? I got as far as

```
$('li.nav').filter() ->
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated https://jsfiddle.net/gadgetgirl/grdkupaz/.  Got it working with

```
$('li.nav a span').filter((i,elem) -> elem.innerHTML is "Two").closest("a").addClass "my-class-name"
```

Thanks for getting me started.